# Lion not getting installed properly

Tags: macos

I bought a used Mac that only had Windows 7 installed. The seller didn't have the original OS DVD, and the hard drive only had a single NTFS partition. I downloaded Lion from a torrent, burned it to a DVD and attempted to install it. When I create a user, it errors out and continues to ask me to create a user again and again.

How do I get past the user creation step?

Comment: Which mac do you have?

Comment: And what OS did it ship with?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to not download a copy of OS X from a torrent, you never know what you are getting.

1. Obtain a legal, trusted copy of OS X. [If your Mac supports it you can get Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/) for $19.99 USD from the App Store, if not you can order OS X Lion from apple for probably around $29.99.

   - Borrow a friends Mac, visit a Mac at an Apple Store, etc., log in to Mac App Store using your Apple ID.
   - Buy and download OS X.
   - [Make a boot-able USB OS X installer](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/17/make-bootable-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-usb-install-drive/)
   - Log out of app store
   - Delete the installer you downloaded.
2. Boot from that copy, by holding down the option key while booting your mac.
3. Run Disk Utility from the OS X install media, erase the entire hard drive.
4. Install OS X
5. Enjoy...